# How can I prevent a link to Jira in Bitbucket Markdown?

Tags: bitbucket, markdown, jira

In a comment on Bitbucket, I would like to use a notation that is automatically converted to a link to a Jira issue, but prevent the linkage: "QNX-6" is the term I'm using (in a quote, otherwise I'd just leave out the dash), is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out by trying because it's not in the docs:

The link can be prevented by preceding the `-` with a `\` as in "QNX\-6".